# TBB flow graph conditional execution AND multiple in - and outputs

Tags: c++, multithreading, intel, tbb, tbb-flow-graph

I've read [TBB flow graph conditional execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819095/tbb-flow-graph-conditional-execution) and have a slightly different problem.

Is it possible to create a node with multiple inputs and multiple outputs AND to control the execution by a conditional variable? Maybe without ugly casts.

I've attached a simple example how I would like to design the graph. How is the besst way to get it run with TBB flow graph?

1. `start_node` sends a `start_msg` to `some_node`
2. if `start_msg` is empty, `some_node` sends a `continue_msg` to `end_node`, else `some_node` sends  a `continue_msg` to itself AND a `data_msg` to `end_node`
3. if `continue_msg` is received by `some_node`, previous start_msg is checked if it's empty, if so, a `continue_msg` is send to `end_node`, else a `data_msg` is send.

   ```
                        +--continue_msg--+
                        |                |
                        +-----+    +-----+
                              |    |
                              |    |   +----data_msg---+
                              v    |  /                 \
   start_node --start_msg--> some_node                    end_node
                                      \                  /
                                       +--continue_msg--+
   ```

One problem I'm dealing with: I can't say how many good elements are inside of `start_msg` even is the size is known (let's say `start_msg` holds a `tbb::concurrent_vector<T>`. If `some_node` finds a bad element, it will be ignored and `some_node` is sending a `continue_msg` to itself.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, the [`source_node`](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/flow_graph/source_node_cls.html) can be used in your algorithm. `source_node` can generate as many messages as you need. So the algorithm can be reworked a bit:

```
source_node -> ... -> end_node
```

Why do you need a `continue_msg` to be sent to the `end_node`? To mark the last message? Perhaps, you can use a `std::pair<T,bool>` where the first element is data and the second one is an indication of the last message.

The Body of the `source_node` finds the valid element in `tbb::concurrent_vector<T>`, creates a new message `make_pair(Data, false)` and returns `true` for each Body invocation. When the last element is extracted from the container it creates `make_pair(Data, true)` and returns `false` as an indication of the last element.

Unfortunately, I do not know the original algorithm and my suggestion can be inappropriate. Could you provide more details if it does not suit your needs, please?